# p:calendar onselect/onchange not fired

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am trying to have two Javascript functions that are being called as soon as a user selects a date from a p:calendar.

Unfortunately, the onchange event is only being processed if the user types a date manually in the text field and tabs forward. The onselect event is not being fired at all.

The xhtml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="custom.js" target="body" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:log />
    <h:form id="someForm">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="myCalendar" value="Date: " />
            <p:calendar id="myCalendar" onchange="alertDateSelected()" onselect="alertSelectEvent()" showOn="button" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The Javascript code for the onselect and onchange events:

```
function alertDateSelected() {
    PrimeFaces.info('Selected date from p:calendar');
}

function alertSelectEvent() {
    PrimeFaces.info('Clicked p:calendar date selection button');
}
```

Is there a possibility to hook to the onchange/onselect event on p:calendar; e.g. if the user selects a date from the calendar panel or via the "Today" button? If so, what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is in the proper location and hence being properly loaded? You should be looking in your javascript console for clues

Comment: @kolossus Yes, I am sure. If you add  `<p:inputText id="myInput" onchange="alertDateSelected()"/>`, the onchange event gets fired and you can see the expected output in the PrimeFaces log. After adding a breakpoint to the function, the reported behaviour is confirmed: script stops if you deal with a `p:inputText` but does not stop if you deal with a `p:calendar`. Please let me know how to get clues from the console if the event does not get fired. Where am I to look for hints on that?

Answer (score 3):

Try it with ajax event lister. For example something like that:

```
        <p:calendar id="myCalendar">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="alertDateSelected" global="false" />
        </p:calendar>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have a quick dialog pop-up and do some basic CSS styling in the Javascript code. I would prefer to avoid doing this with some backing beans. How about that?

Answer (score 3):

As of today, it's still not working in PrimeFaces 6.0.

The following approach uses the AJAX event instead. It calls the JavaScript method (`PF('ordersTable').filter()` in this case) when it starts and cancels it instantly via `return false`. This way it only executes the JavaScript code, but does not really send the AJAX request.

```
<p:calendar onchange="PF('ordersTable').filter()" onselect="PF('ordersTable').filter()">
    <!-- The JS onchange and onselect events don't work. We "misuse" an AJAX event instead. -->
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" onstart="PF('ordersTable').filter();return false;" global="false" />
</p:calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onSelect` instead of `onChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="clickButton('searchFormRegUser:searchButton')" />
```

The problem was that I kept onchange event defined inside p:calendar and also this one (it remained because I was trying out a few things and forgot to delete another one). When I deleted onchange from p:calendar, this worked. I know this is old, but maybe someone else has a similar problem, so I'm posting.